# Can I upgrade my EC2 Package on AWS at anytime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to run cPanel/WHM on EC2. 
I see the different packages that exist.

My question is: Can I upgrade my server resources anytime based on increasements in my demands?

For example: if my current package is "t2.large" can I in the future upgrade the server resources to "m4.2xlarge" or more without any change or effects on my data?

How does it work? 
I mostly run out CPU on every server I create. So that I have to buy a new server which involves lots extra expenses such as cPanel/WHM licenses, etc.

I am looking for a service that I can increase/upgrade server resources such as CPU (most important), RAM, Diskspace.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: "without any change or effects on my data",  answer for this depends on where your data is. Can you upgrade to larger instances, yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why am I getting down voted? Is it wrong to not know something and ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resize your instance anytime you want, but you have to stop your instance to resize it. AWS will choose a new physical hardware based on your new instance type. There are some restrictions on what instance type you can upgrade to depending on virtualization type, region etc., For more information:

[Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Amazon EC2 does not have pricing packages**. It is a pay-as-you-go service, where you are charged for whatever you consume. If you turn off a service, you are no longer charged for it.

You can **change the size** of an Amazon EC2 instance at any time. Simply stop it, change the Instance Type, then start it again. It's just like rebooting a computer. The instance is charged on an hourly basis, so you'll be charged a different hourly rate after you start it again.

If you wish to lock-in a discounted rate (once you know the size of instance you desire), you can purchase an [Amazon EC2 Reserved Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-reserved-instances.html). Despite the name, it is mostly a pricing discount. You pay up-front annually or monthly and receive a discounted charge.

Alternatively, you could use [Amazon Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/), which does offer a **package** consisting of an Instance Type, disk storage and network bandwidth. This is good if you just require a simple machine without the need for complex configuration.